# Conditional Rendering through a function is always False

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate in an array of choices, displaying them as `alert-secondary`; it will however render a choice as `alert-success` if that choice is the *correct answer*. The *correct answer* is based on an array called `answers` that looks like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, question_id: 1, correct_choice_id: 2}
]
```

So I render them:

```
{GetChoices(question._id).map(choice => (
    <div key={choice._id}>
        { IsAnswer(question._id, choice._id) === true
             ?
             <div className="alert alert-success mb-1">
                 {choice.content}
             </div>
             :
             <div className="alert alert-secondary mb-1">
                  {choice.content}
             </div>
        }
     </div>
 ))}
```

`GetChoices` and `IsAnswer`:

```
const GetChoices = (question_id) => {
    let question_choices = []
    choices.forEach((choice) => {
        if (choice.question === question_id) question_choices.push(choice)
    })
    return question_choices
}

const IsAnswer = (question_id, choice_id) => {
    answers.forEach((answer) => {
        if (answer.question_id === question_id && answer.correct_choice_id === choice_id) {
            console.log("yes")
            return true
        }
    })
    console.log("no")
    return false
}
```

However, it renders all choices as `alert-secondary`- meaning all of them returned False in `IsAnswer`.

But as you can see, I placed a `console.log` there and the results were:

```
no
no
yes
```

So in theory, the third choice should be rendered as `alert-success`, but it doesn't.
Any advices/solutions on why it keeps saying False in my conditional rendering?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind everyone, I got it like this:

```
const GetChoices = (question_id) => {
    let question_choices = []
    choices.forEach((choice) => {
        if (choice.question === question_id) {
            // Clone choice
            let new_choice = choice

            // Check if the choice is a correct answer
            answers.forEach((answer) => {
                if (answer.content === choice._id) {
                    new_choice.is_answer = true
                }
            })

            question_choices.push(new_choice)
        }
    })
    return question_choices
}
```